# Capture output from node command in Python

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a javascript file that I run with `node` command in the terminal

**jstest.js**

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(args[0]);

var jsonata = require("jsonata");

var data = JSON.parse(args[0]);
var expression = jsonata(args[1]);
var result = expression.evaluate(data);
console.log(result);
```

In the terminal

```
node jstest3.js '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}' '$sum(example.value)'
```

Now I need to run this command through Python.So I use the subprocess module of Python to do the task

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['node', 'jstest3.js', '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}', '$sum(example.value)'])
print(result)
```

But I get three values as output

```
{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}
11
CompletedProcess(args=['node', 'jstest3.js', '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}', '$sum(example.value)'], returncode=0)
```

But I just want the value **11**.I looked up in the documentation and tried the below techniques

```
result = subprocess.run(['node', 'jstest3.js', '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}', '$sum(example.value)'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)

b'{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}\n11\n'


result = subprocess.call(['node', 'jstest3.js', '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}', '$sum(example.value)'])
print(result)

{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}
11
0
```

How do I get only the result of the expression that is **11**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output of a program in a bytes sequence by calling [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and split it by '\n' to extract the output. To get the output only, you can slice the array to remove the args.

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output([
    'node', 'jstest.js',
    '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}',
    '$sum(example.value)'
])

# capture all the logged lines from the node process    
result = output.split(b'\n')[1:-1]
for line in result:
    print(line.decode('utf-8'))

# output
11
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the result string and get the last stdout line (11) before the returncode (0)

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output([
    'node', 'jstest.js',
    '{"example": [{"value": 2},{"value": 4},{"value": 5}]}',
    '$sum(example.value)'
])

result = output.split('\n')[-2]
```

Comment: Sorry check_call does only check the returncode, therefore check_output is the correct function